# Bind unbound Services in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I'm developing a Android Service. I would like the service to run even when the application not is active. So I start it without binding it:

```
startService(new Intent(Service.class.getName()));
```

Now it will run continuously until I choose to stop it, right?

If I, from another activity, bind the service will it stop when I unbind it?

Comment: Ok, I will. But how do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. However, you have to remember that if there is memory pressure, it may be killed depending on the priorities (and if it is unbound, any visible app will probably have higher priority). The lifecycle is described here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle

Answer (score 1):

When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service (**unless the service was also started by startService()**).

It mean that your service will not stop even you unbind service from all activity in case of you had started service as startService()

For more details about bound service follow bellow link

[Bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Basics)